# SQL Azure response is too slow

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a "Free Trial" account in Azure, I have published a webapp and configured a SQL Server instance (with a database on it).

The webapp should work with the database, the connection string is already configured and it works ok.

The problem is the response time for each query in the database.

e. g.
I have a `Gridview` with a `SQLDataSource`, and a `Select` works ok but takes more than 15 seconds.

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DatosMiercoles" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CATOPSConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Dealer.IDDealer, Batch.IDBatch, Lpars.Nombre, Dealer.DealerCodigo, Batch.Nombre AS Expr1, Batch.CTStart AS Expr2 FROM Lpars INNER JOIN Dealer ON Lpars.IDLpar = Dealer.IDLpar INNER JOIN Batch ON Dealer.IDDealer = Batch.IDDealer INNER JOIN [3Wednesday] ON Batch.IDBatch = [3Wednesday].IDBatch WHERE (Batch.Status = 'Enabled') ORDER BY Batch.CTStart"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Why is this happening? how can I make the response faster? Could be the "FreeTrial" Azure account?

FYI: the server plan I have selected is "B - Basic / 5 DTUs"

[image]

Comment: FreeTrial has not do with it, specified server plan though will determine the SQL performance

Comment: the server plan I have selected is "B - Basic / 5 DTUs"

Comment: What is your basis for comparison? Do you have a local server with exacly the same data and indexes performing very better than sql azure? Also a suggestion: only for testing, try to increase the sql azure perfomance to S2 or higher and verify if you get shorter execution time. Last: verify that Azure web app and sql azure are in the same datacenter.

Comment: Expanding on Fabrizio's comment, when faced with this question - and before others can help, you have to distinguish whether it is a design problem, a data problem, or a server problem. 1) What happens when you run the query against the azure server from your local machine (using SSMS), 2) What is performance like if you install SQL Express locally, and run the query against the exact same data set? The answers to those questions will go a long way to solving your problem.

Comment: Download SSMS and run the query using SSMS against the same Azure database. That isolates any potential issues with your app plus you get to look at the query plan and various useful statistics of the query. With the joins in your query, it's quite possible that you're making SQL DB go to disk a lot and if you don't have the right indexes in place, you might be scanning each time.

Comment: Thanks all for the responses. I have detected the issue, is not with the Server at all. The slow response is inside the application controller. I'm trying to change it now. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the responses. I have detected the issue, is not with the Server at all. 
I have tried changing the button event, and I've detected that the response issue is because the event inside the application controller. I'm trying to change it now. Thanks again